# Kibana plugin resources

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins, kibana, elasticsearch-plugin

Heyy, I'm looking for up-to-date kibana plug-in resources to help me learn and understand how to develop one.

All the resources I've found are out-of-date.
Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Hava you tried these? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/known-plugins.html

Comment: The next tutorial it's on kibana 4 but the author mention kibana 5 as well https://www.timroes.de/2015/12/02/writing-kibana-4-plugins-basics/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest understanding plugin directory structure for [traffic plugin](https://github.com/sbeyn/kibana-plugin-traffic-sg) which would be one of simplest plugin to understand and you could directly add it to your installed plugin folder in kibana and see it working.

Other than that I would also suggest you do read [Tim Roes blogs](https://www.timroes.de/2015/12/02/writing-kibana-4-plugins-basics/) for developing kibana plugins.

Last I would also suggest to use [elasticsearch discussion forum](https://discuss.elastic.co) for kibana related issues as well for quicker responses.

As kibana has different js files which loaded synchrnized way. you can use as it required.